# How to split data by column of Excel Workbooks from an Access Database

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, automation

i have a code that splits data by a specific column value creating new sheets with values name. The code works perfectly on Excel VBA, although i wanted to use it from Access and to control an external workbook that the user choose though FileDialog. I'm running some test inserting the path of excel files i want to split but it works ONLY THE FIRST TIME, the even if i quit without saving it doesn't work anymore. Here's the code (i did some changes for referencing to excel):

```
Dim lr As Long
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim vcol, i As Integer
Dim icol As Long
Dim myarr As Variant
Dim title As String
Dim titlerow As Integer
Dim xTRg As Excel.Range
Dim xVRg As Excel.Range
Dim xWSTRg As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim exapp As Excel.Application


Set exapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = exapp.Workbooks.Open("xxx\Desktop\New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx")
exapp.Visible = True

On Error Resume Next

Set xTRg = wb.ActiveSheet.Range("1:1") 'header (same for all sheets)
Set xVRg = wb.ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B1000") 'range of data to be splitted (i will change for .end(xlup) method)
vcol = xVRg.Column
Set ws = xTRg.Worksheet
lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
title = xTRg.AddressLocal
titlerow = xTRg.Cells(1).Row
icol = ws.Columns.Count
ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"
exapp.DisplayAlerts = False
If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('xTRgWs_Sheet!A1')") Then
    wb.Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "xTRgWs_Sheet"
Else
    wb.Sheets("xTRgWs_Sheet").Delete
    wb.Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "xTRgWs_Sheet"
End If
Set xWSTRg = wb.Sheets("xTRgWs_Sheet")
xTRg.Copy
xWSTRg.Paste Destination:=xWSTRg.Range("A1")
ws.Activate
For i = (titlerow + xTRg.Rows.Count) To lr
    On Error Resume Next
    If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And exapp.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
        ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
    End If
Next
myarr = exapp.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
ws.Columns(icol).Clear
For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
    ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
    If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
    wb.Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
Else
    wb.Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
End If
    xWSTRg.Range(title).Copy
    wb.Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Paste Destination:=Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
    ws.Range("A" & (titlerow + xTRg.Rows.Count) & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A" & (titlerow + xTRg.Rows.Count))
    wb.Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
Next
    xWSTRg.Delete




ws.AutoFilterMode = False
ws.Activate
exapp.DisplayAlerts = True
```

i don't get any error, the excel file just opens and starts filtering/scrolling without creating new sheets.

Comment: `If Not Evaluate` looks like it's implicitly referencing `Excel.Application`, but it's not qualified (`exapp.Evaluate`). Pretty sure such implicit `Application` references translate into ghost EXCEL.EXE processes in Task Manager, and can have *interesting* side-effects, such as code not quite working as expected, or working fine once and then not working subsequent times. Are you quitting/closing the Excel app somewhere?

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next`. Still no errors?

Comment: As i said, it gives me error on Evaluate Statement (i also tried exapp.evaluate)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon i quit the excel workbook when it opens, although i see in task manager that there's an excel process running background and using no CPU at all

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly with evaluating `ISREF` given what's obviously a cell reference? Also, if you have any EXCEL.EXE ghost processes in Task Manager, kill them before retrying, and verify that they're gone when your macro completes. Implicit `Excel.Application` references (like that unqualified `Evaluate` call`) are responsible for that ghost process.

Comment: There are a number of unqualified references to Excel objects, constants etc in your code, which Access won't recognize ( or will recognize as something different to what was intended).  Eg `xlUp`, `Worksheets.Count`, `xlCellTypeConstants`, `Evaluate`, `Sheets` - adding `Option Explicit` will catch these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(A) "i don't get any error" is expected since your code is suppressing errors with `On Error Resume Next`. It's better practice to limit `On Error Resume Next` to trapping a potential error from a short segment of code, then immediately turn errors back on with `On Error Goto 0`.

(B) Also, I don't think Access has `Evaluate` --- you may need to make that Excel-specific with `exapp.Evaluate(...)`.

Comment: i already tried with exapp.evaluate and nothing changed. I will try without on error resume next. The thing weird form me is that it only work the first time. EDIT: without error handling is giving me mismatch error on If not exapp.evaluate statement